Помогите, пожалуйста, оптимизировать код!
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void selection_sort(vector<int>& a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)a.size() - 1; ++i) {
        int imax = i;  // imin
        for (int j = i + 1; j < a.size(); ++j) {
            if (a[j] > a[imax]) // <
                imax = j;
        }
        swap(a[i], a[imax]);
    }
}

int main() {
    int n, k, input;
    cin >> n >> k;
    vector<int> v(n);

    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        cin >> input;
        v[i] = input;
    }

    selection_sort(v);
    cout << v[k-1];
}


У вас есть непринятый ответ на ваш вопрос.

Нужно любым способом оптимизировать код. Главное, чтобы был без использования встроенных функций

Не совсем понял вопрос. Имеется ввиду оптимизировать конкретно этот код или в принципе оптимизировать код.

Если вы хотите использовать именно сортировку выбором, которую описали, то особо предложить нечего. Вы не сможете выжать из нее столько, чтобы она была быстрее других алгоритмов. Ее сложность все равно останется O(n^2)

Могу только предложить использовать size_t и убрать повторные вызовы size(), но все это мало повлияет на скорость работы

Вероятно, сортировка вообще не нужна

Из кода похоже, что нужно найти минимальное значение в массиве. Для этого сортировать вообще  не нужно, достаточно одного прохода, аналогичного вашему поиску imax (только с минимумом)

Ну, в первую очередь следует избавиться от лишних вызовов функции size();
void selection_sort(vector<int>& a)
{
    int s = a.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < s - 1; ++i) {
        int imax = i;  // imin
        for (int j = i + 1; j < s; ++j) {
            if (a[j] > a[imax]) // <
                imax = j;
        }
        swap(a[i], a[imax]);
    }
}

